# Time taken for a lake shaped like a frustum of a cone to freeze

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, temperature, thermal-conductivity, heat-conduction

My textbook had the derivation for time taken for freezing of a lake having uniform cross sectional area. But I wondered lakes generally are not cuboidal. Yes I know lakes are not even frustum shaped but frustum is a more accurate picture I think. I just needed help in deriving time taken to freeze this frustum shaped lake.
Given that:
1.Assume water is not at 4°C but at 0°C
2.Larger radius(at the top) = R_l and smaller radius(at the bottom) = R_s
3.Height of lake = H
4.Surrounding atmosphere is at -T°C
5.Time is taken only in conduction through ice and not in conversion of water into ice
6.Density of water at 0°C = D_w
7.Latent heat of fusion of water = L_f
8.Conductivity of ice = K_i.
Yes some of these assumptions though obviously not real were taken in uniform cross sectional case also so I thought to keep them here also otherwise it would get way too real and therefore way too hard to derive I guess.
Thank you.

Comment: One possible approach would be to think of your frustum as a lot of very thin layers, with each individual layer having a uniform cross section.  You know how to calculate for each layer and a boundary condition will be shared between the bottom of one layer and the top of the next.

Comment: Please review your question to make it more clear. Moreover, please format formulae by using the math mode in the editor.